# Python Requests data parameter not working properly

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm using Requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

I'm trying to do a simple POST request with some extra headers. I don't understand the following behavior.

```
opener = requests.Session()
data = {"payload" : { "id": 1, "pwd": "mypass"}
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
url = "https://mysite.com/login"    

# THIS WORKS
opener.post(url, data)
# THIS DOES NOT WORK
opener.post(url, json.dumps(data))

# THIS DOES NOT WORK
opener.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
# THIS WORKS
opener.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

It seems that the post method expects a `dict` normally and does not work when I convert that `dict` to a `string`. I can login using the former but I can't using the latter.

However, when I supply extra headers information, it seems the post method works the extact opposite way, it expects a string for the data. On the server side, the first version throws an error while the second version works with headers.

What is the reason for this behavior?